# Update XML column of a table in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have a table named DateRule in sql server 2008R2 and I am trying to update a XML column value but it's not working as expected.

- DateRuleId: 40
- Description: 2 Months after Date step started
- DateRuleXml:

  ```
          <Daterule>
              <Type>Timespan</Type>
              <months>2</months>
              <days>0</days>
              <hours>0</hours>
              <minutes>0</minutes>
              <seconds>0</seconds>
              <After>1</After>
              <Reference>1</Reference>
          </Daterule>
  ```

The query i am trying to run is:

```
update centralq3.wf.DateRule
set DateRuleXml.modify('replace value of (/Daterule/@Reference)[1] with "6"')
where DateRuleId = 40
```

And:

```
update centralq3.wf.DateRule
set DateRuleXml.modify('replace value of (//@Reference)[1] with "6"')
where DateRuleId = 40
```

They both succed and say (1 row(s) affected), but the value of Reference is not changed. What I am doing wrong? I know there are many question regarding to this, but didn't help me..

**Edit!!**
**Answer:**

```
UPDATE centralq3.wf.DateRule
SET DateRuleXml.modify('replace value of (/Daterule/Reference[1]/text())[1] with "6"')
WHERE DateRuleId = 40
```

Comment: Try this : `set DateRuleXml.modify('replace value of (/Daterule/@Reference)[.=1][1] with "6"')` alone

Comment: Succeded, shown me that 1 row is affected but still nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will :

```
SET DateRuleXml.modify('replace value of (/Daterule/Reference[1]/text())[1] with "6"');
```